# Control Show/Hide multiple DIV using CSS, Javascript, and Anchor without unique ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I have an older JavaScript/CSS file that used to (no longer works in current browsers) toggle the display properties for multiple `div`s by way of anchor tags. The CSS document.stylesheets would toggle based on value "rules", that required the style to be in a specific sequence to control the "none" to "block" toggling (or the reverse). Here is a link to the JSFiddle example: 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oliver2/n5onp52x/)

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function NorB(arg){
if (arg=="n") {
    document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.display=='block';
    document.styleSheets[0].rules[1].style.display=='none';
} else {
    document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.display=='none';
    document.styleSheets[0].rules[1].style.display=='block';
}
```

}

Here is the HTML:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="narrative" id="rpmAct1">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="narButton"><a href="javascript: onClick=NorB('n')">Narrative ></a></div>
            <div class="bulButton"><a href="javascript: onClick=NorB('b')">List View ></a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="narrativeContent">
            <div class="n">Narrative text</div>
            <div class="b">
                <ul>
                    <li>List Item A</li>
                    <li>List Item B</li>
                    <li>List ITem C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    </td>                   
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="narrative" id="rpmAct2">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="narButton"><a href="javascript: onClick=NorB('n')">Narrative 2></a></div>
            <div class="bulButton"><a href="javascript: onClick=NorB('b')">List View 2></a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="narrativeContent">
            <div class="n">Narrative 2 text</div>
            <div class="b">
                <ul>
                    <li>List 2 Item A</li>
                    <li>List 2 Item B</li>
                    <li>List 2 ITem C</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    </td>                   
    </tr>

</table>
```

And lastly, the CSS:

```
        .n {
        display:block;
    }
    .b {
        display:none;
    }
    .b ul {
        margin-left:3px;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-right:10px;
        margin-bottom:-2px;
    }
    .b ul li {
        list-style-type:square;
        list-style-position:outside;
        line-height:12px;
    }
    .buttons {
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
    }
    .narButton {
        width:80px;
        float:left;
        padding:2px 0px 2px 5px;    
    }
    .bulButton {
        width:80px;
        float:left;
        padding:2px 0px 2px 5px;
    }
    .bulButton a, .narButton a {
        font-size:14px;
        font-style:normal;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .narrativeContent {
        border-top:1px solid #CCC;
        border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
        padding:5px;
    }
```

Since there is a large number of `div`/`anchor` elements on the page, the goal is to avoid creating unique IDs for each, and continue to use basic CSS/JavaScript (avoid using jQuery and the like). Thoughts on how to keep this simple?

Comment: This is usually done by changing classes of the elements, not by changing the CSS on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append these CSS

```
.b-mode .b, .n-mode.n {
    display:block;
}
.b-mode .n, .n-mode.b {
    display:none;
}
```

Modify onclick action

```
<a href="#" onclick="NorB(this,'n')">
```

Modify Javascript

```
function NorB(e, arg) {
    var wrapper = e.parents('.narrative');
    var rm = arg == 'n' ? 'b' : 'n';
    wrapper.classList.add(arg + '-mode');
    wrapper.classList.remove(rm + '-mode');
}
Object.prototype.parents = function (selector) {
    if (selector.length == 0) return;
    var prefix = selector.substr(0, 1);
    if (prefix != '#' && prefix != '.') return;
    var selector = selector.substr(1);
    var p = this.parentNode;
    while (p !== null) {
        switch (prefix) {
            case "#":
                if (p.getAttribute('id') == selector) return p;
                break;
            case ".":
                if (p.classList.contains(selector)) return p;
                break;
        }
        p = p.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ypnospae/

Comment: Not quite. Each row has two buttons that toggle between a short text messages and a set of list items. Each row works independently of all other rows, but in this jsfiddle clicking on one row toggles the other row as well. Since the class name is the same for each row, I would expect each occurrence to toggle across all the rows.

Comment: Most awesome! Thought I was going to be stuck using the DIV IDs to sort through and find the class specific to what was being toggled. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Parfait's script is exactly what was needed:

```
function NorB(e, arg) {
    var wrapper = e.parents('.narrative');
    var rm = arg == 'n' ? 'b' : 'n';
    wrapper.classList.add(arg + '-mode');
    wrapper.classList.remove(rm + '-mode');
}
Object.prototype.parents = function (selector) {
    if (selector.length == 0) return;
    var prefix = selector.substr(0, 1);
    if (prefix != '#' && prefix != '.') return;
    var selector = selector.substr(1);
    var p = this.parentNode;
    while (p !== null) {
        switch (prefix) {
            case "#":
                if (p.getAttribute('id') == selector) return p;
                break;
            case ".":
                if (p.classList.contains(selector)) return p;
                break;
        }
        p = p.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
};
```

Learning every day, and the mentoring is greatly appreciated!